# How to get url from a page that has pagination?

Tags: php

I want to get url from 5 page at the same time so I write my code like this

```
<?php
  $getLinks = "http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/";
  for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    $result = $getLinks.$i;
    $urls = file_get_contents($result);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($urls);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//div[contains(@class, 'featured') or contains(@class, 'premium')]//a");

    for($i=0; $i<$hrefs->length; $i++) {
        $href = $hrefs->item($i);
        $url = $href->getAttribute('href').PHP_EOL;
        echo $url."<br />";
    }
 }
?>
```

Here

```
$getLinks = "http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/";
  for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++){
    $result = $getLinks.$i;
```

will output

```
http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/1
http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/2
http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/3
http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/4
http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/5
```

each of this 5 url  has different 20 url. I want to loop all of them to get all the url.

So if I loop 5 url above I will get 100 url. But in my code above doesn't work I can get only 20 url form  http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/1.

Please help me everyone; Thanks.

Comment: Your title and your description not fit and understand what you want!

Comment: @pov I want to get 100 url from http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/1
http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/2
http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/3
http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/4
http://realestate.com.kh/real-estate-for-sale-in/all/5

Answer (score 0):

your code seemed to be right except a tiny mistake which is as follows:

in both of your **for Loop** you are using the same variable **$i** as a loop iteration variable,

> your second for loop, changes the value of $i and this value is used
>   by your first for loop.

I suggest you to change at least the second for loop iteration variable name. for e.g. replace **$i** with **$j** in your second for loop.